# ReferenceError: Property 'Reflect' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, gradle, react-native-hermes

I am trying to enable `hermes` in my react native app by following this https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes in react native website but I get this error message :
`ReferenceError: Property 'Reflect' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes`
My RN version : `0.63.4`

Thank you in avance

Comment: If you search for this in the hermes repo, there are some useful issue threads, like this: https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/259

Comment: Hello @Kai thank you for your answer but I already try this and not solve my problem

Comment: @Pvkndux did you fixed it? I got the same error.

Comment: @ruin3936 I did not fix this, sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 5):

#### If you saw this error immediately without installing any library

Check your latest change in code, it might be a syntax error. For me, I typed some characters mistakenly
Check recent git changes

Comment: your answer is amazing!

Answer (score -1):

Edit your android/app/build.gradle file

```
project.ext.react = [entryFile: "index.js",]
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, editing my `metro.config.js` file from

```js
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['bin', 'txt', 'jpg', 'png', 'ttf'],
    sourceExts: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'jsx'],
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/platform_node/]),
  },
};
```

to:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['bin', 'txt', 'jpg', 'png', 'ttf'],
    sourceExts: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'jsx'],
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/platform_node/]),
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

Resolved the issue.